# Из-за чего появляется ошибка NullPointerException

Tags: java

Изучаю язык Java относительно недавно (есть опыт написание приложений под C++ OpenGL GLSL). Решил написать бота, по типу вопрос-ответ, логику набросал, скомпилировали - появляется ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Вот лог выполнения:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at iostream.Main.main(Main.java:16)
/home/hays/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned:  

СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

Вот исходники, словарь с ключами и значениями считывается из файла и парсятся в `HashMap` *data.txt*

> Как дела ?!|Хорошо как у тебя ?!
>   Тоже не плохо|Я рада!
>   Как вас зовут?|Холо

Класс Main:

```
package iostream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static IOStream StreamIO;
    private static Parser Holo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String patch = "data.txt";
        StreamIO = new IOStream(patch);
        String Text = StreamIO.read();
        System.out.println(Text);
        System.out.println(StreamIO.NumOFphrases());
        Holo.ParseString(Text, StreamIO.NumOFphrases());
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String question = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Holo.DiologHolo.get(question));
    }
}
```

Класс Parser:

```
package iostream;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parser {

    public Map DiologHolo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public boolean SetKeyValue(String Key,String Value) 
    {
        if(Key.isEmpty() && Value.isEmpty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            DiologHolo.put(Key, Value);
        }

       return true;
    }

    public void ParseString(String Text,int NumOFphrases) 
    {         
        String KeyValue[] = Text.split("|");  // по пробелу
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOFphrases; i+=2) {
            System.out.println(KeyValue[i]);
            System.out.println(KeyValue[i++]);            
            SetKeyValue(KeyValue[i],KeyValue[i++]);            
        }
    }

}
```

Класс IOStream:

```
package iostream;

import java.io.*;

public class IOStream {

    // класс для чтения файла
    private InputStream inputstream;

    // класс для записи в файл
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    // путь к файлу который будем читать и записывать
    private String path;

    private int Numofphrases=0;

    public int NumOFphrases(){
    return this.Numofphrases;
    }

    public IOStream(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    // чтение файла используя InputStream
    public String read() throws IOException {
        // инициализируем поток на чтение
        inputstream = new FileInputStream(path);
        int byteChar;        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while( (byteChar=inputstream.read())!=-1 )
        {
            baos.write( byteChar );
            if('|'==(char)byteChar)
            {
                Numofphrases++;
            }
        }
        // закрываем поток
        inputstream.close();        
        return baos.toString();
    }

    // запись в файл используя OutputStream
    public void write(String st) throws IOException {
        // инициализируем поток для вывода данных
        // что позволит нам записать новые данные в файл
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        // передаем полученную строку st и приводим её к byte массиву.
        outputStream.write(st.getBytes());
        // закрываем поток вывода
        // только после того как мы закроем поток данные попадут в файл.
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не проинициализировали `Holo`

```
private static Parser Holo;
```

и пытаетесь воспользоваться его методом

```
Holo.ParseString(Text, StreamIO.NumOFphrases());
```

Нужно проинициализировать объект как-то так

```
private static Parser Holo = new Parser();
```

Comment: private static Parser Holo;
Писал в стили с++... в этом вся проблема

Comment: @hays В стиле с++ считайте, что создаёте ссылки. Как вы там в с++ пишите `Parser *holo = new Parser()`? В java всё ссылки и их не надо помечать никакими звёздочками и прочими закорючками. `Parser holo = new Parser()`

Answer (score 8):

Java выдает:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

в случаях когда происходит обращение к "нулевому" объекту.

Запустите свой код в отладке, найдите где у вас null, добавьте проверку если это нормальное поведение, или же найдите причину, почему объект к которому вы обращаетесь равен null.

Так же рекомендую прочитать [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/221243/) статью, она посвящена этой проблеме и написана как раз для новичков.